# How to know if values includes in array and if exist push to array?

Tags: javascript

I need to push in array data if exist in array?
Example code:

```
  filterMealType(type){ 
        this.filteredRecipe.map(
          obj => { 
            if(obj.mealTypes.includes(type)){
              this.filterRecipeByMealType.push(obj) 
            }else {
              this.filterRecipeByMealType = []
            }
          }
        )
        console.log('current array ', this.filterRecipeByMealType)
      }
```

type as parameter is only number, 0 or 1 or 2 or 3.
filteredRecipe is array:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Obroki",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":4,
      "preparationTime":1920,
      "ingredients":[
         "dsad",
         "dasdas"
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "sad",
         "dsa"
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.url.com/images/cb51adad61a04936b831378865ad8bf6.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         0,
         2
      ],
      "id":281
   },
   {
      "name":"Testen",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":3,
      "preparationTime":240,
      "ingredients":[
         "sestavino",
         "test"
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "inst"
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.url.com/images/aca27231f9af4ed0af5e1ec4af09861e.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         0,
         2
      ],
      "id":282
   },
   {
      "name":"Mleko",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":2,
      "preparationTime":2580,
      "ingredients":[
         "ddd"
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "das",
         "dasd"
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.url.com/images/1fd0bd88175a4680ae9430579f1b781c.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         1
      ],
      "id":283
   },
   {
      "name":"test",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":4,
      "preparationTime":240,
      "ingredients":[
         "jajca",
         "meso"
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "rf"
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.url.com/images/0fafcd552354468bbca3a78cb9796004.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         0,
         2
      ],
      "id":211
   }
]
```

I if obj.mealTypes includes any of number i need to push to array.
Right now no work good. Now i only push one item...no work good.
If you need i can share to stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your else condition and reset your array at the begining of your function

```
 filterMealType(type){ 
    this.filterRecipeByMealType = []
    this.filteredRecipe.map(
      obj => { 
        if(obj.mealTypes.includes(type)){
          this.filterRecipeByMealType.push(obj) 
        }
      }
    )
    console.log('current array ', this.filterRecipeByMealType)
  }
```

Comment: Friend when i select another time second item, my array is not cleared

Comment: I edited my answer in the meantime, did you see it ? The reset at the begining of the function

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter` method on the `filteredRecipe` array to return a new array with only recipes that have the meal type you're looking for.

```
filterMealType(type) { 
  this.filterRecipeByMealType = this.filteredRecipe.filter(
    recipe => recipe.mealTypes.includes(type)
  );
  console.log('current array ', this.filterRecipeByMealType)
}
```